# Anliegen vs. Angelegenheit

Tags: difference, noun

What are the semantic differences between *Anliegen* and *Angelegenheit*? For example, where can one be used where the other can't?

Comment: Use a better online dictionary providing examples and context, as [dwds](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Anliegen).

Comment: @guidot Cheers for the excellent resource; I wasn't aware of that site.

Comment: Wiktionary and Duden also provide examples: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Anliegen http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Anliegen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Angelegenheit* translates directly to "matter". It denotes an unspecific *case* you have with your counterpart or another party (They might have asked you something, you might have asked something, anything you have as dealings with the partner or even with third parties).

A lawyer might write to another one

> In der Angelegenheit Müller gegen Maier sende ich Ihnen in der Anlage die Anklageschrift.

*Anliegen* is more specific - It mainly denotes a *request*, a *wish* or a *specific concern* you might have with the counterpart directly (or they might have with you) - A third party is typically not involved.

A company might write to a customer

> Wegen Ihres Anliegens betreffs Zusendung eines neuen Anwenderhandbuches wenden Sie sich bitte an unsere lokale Niederlassung

(German can be so poetic...)

Answer (score 1):

Eine *Angelegenheit* kann alles sein, was getan/geregelt/behoben werden muss oder soll[te], von der Hochzeit bis zum Reifenwechsel.

> Das Putzen des Badezimmers ist eine unangenehme Angelegenheit.

Bei einem *Anliegen* will A, dass B für A etwas tut (A, B sind jeweils eine oder mehrere Personen).

Typisches Beispiel aus dem Leben:

> Ein Herrscher verurteilt dich zum Tode und kerkert dich ein. Deine
>   Frau besucht ihn mit dem Anliegen, dich zu verschonen. (**Fall 1:** A = eine Person, B = eine Person)

**Fall 2:** A = eine Person, B = mehrere Personen

> Mit dem Anliegen, ihr die Waschmaschine hinunterzutragen, wendet sich
>   Frau K. an zwei sportlich erscheinende Herren.

**Fall 3:** A = mehrere Personen, B = eine Person

> Eine Gruppe Studenten erscheint mit dem Anliegen beim Professor, die
>   Klausur um eine Woche zu verschieben.

**Fall 4:** A und B jeweils mehrere Personen

> Öffentlicher Rasen, 1 Fußball, 2 Mannschaften à 5 Spieler. Die
>   vermeintlich schwächeren 5 haben ein Anliegen – bei Spielbeginn soll
>   es bereits 1:0 für *sie* stehen.

»Anliegen«, das einer eher gehobenen Stilebene angehört, kann in allen Beispielen durch »Wunsch« oder »Bitte« ersetzt werden.

<sub>Please ask for translation</sub>